# Python BeautifulSoup find all error (object has no attribute)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The script below is meant to look through ebay listings on the ebay search page. The search page is just a list, so I am trying to loop through each li tag and add the content to a variable. For some reason this script doesn't seem to want to work and I'm not sure why.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
url = "https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=funko+gamora+199&_sacat=0&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=1&_ipg=200"

# Connect to the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
try:
    page = urlopen(url)
except:
    print("Error opening the URL")

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
content = soup.find('ul', {"class": "srp-results srp-list clearfix"})

#print(content)

article = ''
for i in content.findAll('li'):
    article = article + ' ' +  i.text
print(article)

# Saving the scraped text
with open('scraped_text.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(article)
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: No error for me when running. Did this error appear after several runs?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the response looks like:

```
print(soup.text)
```

> Security measureSkip to main content  Please verify yourself to continueerror To keep eBay a safe place to buy and sell, we will occasionally ask you to verify yourself. This helps us to block unauthorised users from entering our site.Please verify yourselfIf you're having difficulties with the rendering of images on the above verification page, eBay suggests using the latest version of your browser or an alternate browser listed in here   Additional site navigationAbout eBayAnnouncementsCommunitySafety CentreResolution CentreSeller CentreVeRO: Protecting Intellectual PropertyPoliciesHelp & ContactSite MapCopyright © 1995-2021 eBay Inc. All Rights Reserved. User Agreement, Privacy, Cookies and AdChoiceNorton Secured - powered by Verisign

It's an error on ebay-end, your code looks fine at first glance. Also, note that webscraping is a grey area and some companies do not allow it. You might need to bypass security measures.

Also, you should comment your code in such way that tells the reader WHY your code does what it does, not what it does. You don't have to comment things like "soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')"

Edit: I forgot to mention, error appears, because

```
content = soup.find('ul', {"class": "srp-results srp-list clearfix"})
```

found no results.